# PHP date comparison to find birthdays that are before timestamp date 1970?

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

I have created function to generate list of members having birthday 1 week before, today and week after. The function is

```
$m= date("m"); // Month value
        $de= date("d"); //today's date
        $y= date("Y"); // Year value

for($i=0;$i<count($members);$i++){
            $m_bday = strtotime($members[$i]->dob);
            $bday_date = date('d',$m_bday);
            $bday_month = date('m',$m_bday);
            $bday = strtotime(date('Y-m-d',mktime(0,0,0,$bday_month,$bday_date,$y)));
            //echo $bday_date."</br>".$bday_month."</br>".$members[$i]->dob."</br>".date('Y-m-d',$bday);exit;
            $week_before = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0,$m,($de-7),$y)));
            $week_after = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', mktime(0,0,0,$m,($de+7),$y)));

            if(date('d-m') == date('d-m',$bday)){
                $this->present_bday[] = array('mem_name'=> $members[$i]->name);
            }
            else if(date('d-m',$week_before) <= date('d-m',$bday) && date('d-m',$bday) < date('d-m')){
                $this->past_bday[] = array('mem_name' => $members[$i]->name);
            }
            else if(date('d-m')< date('d-m',$bday) && date('d-m',$bday) <= date('d-m',$week_after)){
                $this->future_bday[] = array('mem_name' => $members[$i]->name);
            }
        }
```

The date format returned from the db is `yyyy-mm-dd` i.e `1960-06-12`. This code works fine for 1 week before and today but 1 week after returning if the year is below 1970 and 1 week after condition completely fails.

Can anyone provide me with proper date manipulation for the correct results please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
    <?php
$m= date("m"); // Month value
        $de= date("d"); //today's date
        $y= date("Y"); // Year value

for($i=0;$i<count($members);$i++){

            $mem_bod_explode=explode("-",$members[$i]->dob);
            $m_bday = mktime(0,0,0,$mem_bod_explode[1],$mem_bod_explode[2],$y);
            //$bday_date = date('d',$m_bday);
            //$bday_month = date('m',$m_bday);
            //$bday = $m_bday;
            //echo $bday_date."</br>".$bday_month."</br>".$members[$i]->dob."</br>".date('Y-m-d',$bday);exit;

            $week_before = mktime(0,0,0,$mem_bod_explode[1],$mem_bod_explode[2]-7,$y);
            $week_after = mktime(0,0,0,$mem_bod_explode[1],$mem_bod_explode[2]+7,$y);

           echo  date('Y-m-d',$week_before);
           echo"<br>";
           echo  date('Y-m-d',$week_after);
           echo"<br>";
           echo date('Y-m-d');

            if(date('Y-m-d') == date('Y-m-d',$m_bday)){
                $present_bday[] = array('mem_name'=> $members[$i]->name);
            }
            else if(date('Y-m-d',$m_bday)<date('Y-m-d') && date('Y-m-d',$m_bday)>=date('Y-m-d',$week_before)){
                $past_bday[] = array('mem_name'=> $members[$i]->name);
            }

            else if(date('Y-m-d',$m_bday)>date('Y-m-d') && date('Y-m-d',$m_bday)<=date('Y-m-d',$week_after)){
                $future_bday[] = array('mem_name'=> $members[$i]->name);
            }


        }



        ?>
```

Comment: using explode and mktime will work but when we add days like +7 at the end of year like 30th it ll return 6th of the same month

Comment: No its returning 6 th of next month ,

Comment: hmmm i tried to compare like 1983-10-30 with current date its not returning in the past_bday

Comment: I have edited the code little bit...please use the updated one please.Use $y in place of $mem_bod_explode[0].

Comment: ya i have edited that too .. it should work but some how its not showing result as expected

Comment: srry my bad ur code works fine little trouble with array . Thanks Bro         .

Answer (score 3):

I think that your trouble is because `strtotime` return seconds from UNIX epoch and that's actually 1970. I'd better compare dates directly in database: `SELECT ADDDATE('2008-01-02', INTERVAL 1 WEEK);` or `SELECT SUBDATE('2008-01-02', INTERVAL 1 WEEK);`

You can also do that like this:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
if((integer) $interval->format('%R%a') > 7) // More than week
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code .Hope this will help you.

```
$m= date("m"); // Month value
        $de= date("d"); //today's date
        $y= date("Y"); // Year value

for($i=0;$i<count($members);$i++){

            $mem_bod_explode=explode("-",$members[$i]->dob);
            $m_bday = mktime(0,0,0,$mem_bod_explode[1],$mem_bod_explode[2],$mem_bod_explode[0]);
            $bday_date = date('d',$m_bday);
            $bday_month = date('m',$m_bday);
            $bday = $m_bday;
            //echo $bday_date."</br>".$bday_month."</br>".$members[$i]->dob."</br>".date('Y-m-d',$bday);exit;
            $week_before = mktime(0,0,0,$mem_bod_explode[1],$mem_bod_explode[2]-7,$mem_bod_explode[0]);
            $week_after = mktime(0,0,0,$mem_bod_explode[1],$mem_bod_explode[2]+7,$mem_bod_explode[0]);

            if(date('d-m') == date('d-m',$bday)){
                $this->present_bday[] = array('mem_name'=> $members[$i]->name);
            }
            else if(date('d-m',$week_before) <= date('d-m',$bday) && date('d-m',$bday) < date('d-m')){
                $this->past_bday[] = array('mem_name' => $members[$i]->name);
            }
            else if(date('d-m')< date('d-m',$bday) && date('d-m',$bday) <= date('d-m',$week_after)){
                $this->future_bday[] = array('mem_name' => $members[$i]->name);
            }
        }
```

Comment: i tried its returning same thing. i think i have to do it in db itself as Vyacheslav Voronchuk says.

Answer (score 0):

i compared the dates in database query itself came up  with something like this

```
$res = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) - 7 <= dayofyear(dob) AND DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) +7 >= dayofyear(dob);")->result();
$weekbfr_mem = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) - 7 <= dayofyear(dob) AND dayofyear(dob) < DAYOFYEAR(curdate());")->result();
$bday_mem = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) = dayofyear(dob);")->result();
$weekafter_mem = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) < dayofyear(dob) AND dayofyear(dob) <= DAYOFYEAR(curdate()+7);")->result();
```

the main disad in this i have to make 3 query to server its slow for project.so any idea about doing in php function itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try the below code for testing:
I have putted date 1983-10-30 and its showing in Past.

<?php
    $m= date("m"); // Month value
            $de= date("d"); //today's date
            $y= date("Y"); // Year value

    for($i=0;$i<1;$i++){

                $mem_bod_explode=explode("-","1983-10-30");
                $m_bday = mktime(0,0,0,$mem_bod_explode[1],$mem_bod_explode[2],$y);
                //$bday_date = date('d',$m_bday);
                //$bday_month = date('m',$m_bday);
                //$bday = $m_bday;
                //echo $bday_date."</br>".$bday_month."</br>".$members[$i]->dob."</br>".date('Y-m-d',$bday);exit;

                $week_before = mktime(0,0,0,$mem_bod_explode[1],$mem_bod_explode[2]-7,$y);
                $week_after = mktime(0,0,0,$mem_bod_explode[1],$mem_bod_explode[2]+7,$y);

               echo  date('Y-m-d',$week_before);
               echo"<br>";
               echo  date('Y-m-d',$week_after);
               echo"<br>";
               echo date('Y-m-d');

                if(date('Y-m-d') == date('Y-m-d',$m_bday)){
                    $present_bday[] = array('mem_name'=> "fgfg");
                }
                else if(date('Y-m-d',$m_bday)<date('Y-m-d') && date('Y-m-d',$m_bday)>=date('Y-m-d',$week_before)){
                    $past_bday[] = array('mem_name' => "gfgfg");
                }

                else if(date('Y-m-d',$m_bday)>date('Y-m-d') && date('Y-m-d',$m_bday)<=date('Y-m-d',$week_after)){
                    $future_bday[] = array($members[$i]->name);
                }


            }
            echo"<br>";
         echo"Past Birthday:<br>";   
         print_r($past_bday);
         echo"<br>";

         echo"Present Birthday:<br>";   
         print_r($present_bday);
         echo"<br>";

         echo"Future Birthday:<br>";   
         print_r($future_bday);
         echo"<br>";

            ?>
```